# In Azure CLI, Login command failed. How to fix it?

Tags: azure, azure-cli

In window 10, I try that login azure using cmd.

And the command is like this.

```
azure login -u user@xxx.onmicrosoft.com
```

But login is failed and just show error message

```
error:   self signed certificate in certificate chain
error:   Error information has been recorded to C:\Users\ysulee\.azure\azure.err
error:   login command failed
```

I check login information like accout, password ...

How can i fix it?

Comment: try installing the oldest version of azure cli?

Comment: What Azure CLI version are you on?

Comment: I assume that  there are mutiple verfications for the account. Have you tried to use command `azure login` then it will get a device code. After that visit https://aka.ms/devicelogin from browser to login with account.